# mod_rewrite page beautifying

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

So I'm stuck. I'm not very good with mod_rewrite or regular expressions in general, and this is giving me problems.

I need to redirect url's like
`domain.com/view/Some_Article_Name.html`
to
`domain.com/index.php?p=view&id=Some_Article_Name`

The rule that I have now works fine, but it also rewrites for all my stylesheets and images and stuff that shouldn't be rewritten.
`RewriteRule ^view/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=view&id=$1 [L]`

It should only redirect pages that start with `domain.com/view/*`.I imagine that all I need is a rewritecond, but I can't seem to make one that works. Got any idea what I need to add to this to make it work without writing a rewriterule for every individual file?

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.html [NC]

RewriteRule ^view/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=view&id=$1 [L]`
is my rewrite statement for this.

Comment: I can't see how that `RewriteRule` could possibly match something that doesn't start with `view/`... are you saying that's what it does?

Comment: Yes, that was the case. It was looking for view/style.css rather than style.css. This issue is fixed now. The problem now is the rewritecond to enforce it only for /view/*. I can't seem to figure out how to format comments in this archaic system, so I've added it to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that your stylesheets and images are being affected by this rule. Because that would mean your stylesheets’ and images’ URL paths end with `.html`. Because otherwise the rule won’t be applied.

I rather suppose that you’re using relative URL paths to reference the stylesheets and images like `./css/style.css` or `images/foo/bar.png`. Such relative URL paths are resolved from a base URL path. And that is the URL path of the current document.

Your original URL path had just one path segment and all relative URL paths worked when starting at that point. But now you introduces another path segment (`/view`) and relative paths are resolved from that path. So `./css/style.css` or `images/foo/bar.png` is now resolved to `/view/css/style.css` and `/view/images/foo/bar.png` instead of `/css/style.css` and `/images/foo/bar.png` like it was with `/index.php`.

The solution: Use absolute URL paths like `/css/style.css` or `/images/foo/bar.png` to reference your external resources. With such URL paths the base URL can have any path and the resources are always getting resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want the css & images to live under the original file location (e.g. on `htdocs/view/` where `htdocs` is your source root, but you want the url for the html to be rerouted to the index.php file?

If that is what you're saying, than what you need is a reverse `RewriteRule` as well, since the browser will pick any css/images relative to the redirected url (assuming relative image/css references in html).

Other than that, I agree with @David and can't how anything w/o `view` and `.html` could be matching.